# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributes

I tried writing the code ,

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
session =tf.InteractiveSession()
```

but i got an error 
`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'`

already tried this

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()

tf.reset_default_graph()
session =tf.InteractiveSession()
```

Comment: What is `tf.__version__`?

Comment: 1.19 version...